# How to wrap each top most category in <ul> tags?

Tags: wordpress

I need to wrap each top most category in  tags - wp_list_categories doesn't do it. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

you just have to define the depth of the list to be printed.

These are the possible values u can give for depth.

```
    * 0 - All Categories and child Categories (Default).
    * -1 - All Categories displayed in flat (no indent) form (overrides hierarchical).
    * 1 - Show only top level Categories
    * n - Value of n (some number) specifies the depth (or level) to descend in displaying Categories
```

So what you may need will be something like this

```
<ul>
<?php wp_list_categories('depth=1'); ?>
</ul>
```

Ofcourse u can add more options...

For wordpress doubts you can always refer the following sites:
[www.wprecipes.com](http://www.wprecipes.com)
[www.wpbeginner.com](http://www.wpbeginner.com/)
[wordpresskillertips.blogspot.com](http://wordpresskillertips.blogspot.com/)